# Split tests in multiple docker containers with Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to find a way to automatically split and run tests in different docker containers using Maven.

I had a look at the maven-surefire-plugin and saw that it is possible to use the forkCount configuration parameter to specify the number of concurrent JVM processes that will be used to execute the tests. I was wondering if there was a way to run the processes in separate containers (i.e. one JVM process per container).

Comment: are these containers that can run at the same time? so started together, then tests run against the container they need to use and then be stopped together? this would be possible using the fabric8 maven plugin and the failsafe plugin (in the pre/post integration-test phases in maven). If you need more control per test you may have a look at https://www.testcontainers.org/

Comment: Yes, the idea is having the containers start and run groups of tests in parallel to reduce the overall build time. (the tests I want to run are acceptance tests, so thought that running them inside containers would provide better isolation when running them in parallel)

Comment: The same image several times? Or different images? The containers run on the same hardware so the forkCount of the plugin might be good enough for parallelism (beside isolation). You would need to mount the build and maven repo into the containers and specify which tests to run. Using the fabric8 plugin this would be done per test container you start. quite some xml. If you would shell script this step that may look easier, but both surefire and failsafe plugins require a project - you would go through all phases again. I think this is stretching the maven capabilities quite a bit.

Comment: You could also try parallel execution of test classes which is capability provided by maven surefire plugin. This link explains it: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html. Please ignore if you have already tried this capability.